# How to Revalidate a Specific Dynamic Segment (/product/123) in Next.js Without Revalidating All Segments (/product/[id])? - Next.js 13.4.6

Tags: next.js, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I am working on a **Next.js** project **version 13.4.6** and I have a **dynamic route /product/[id]**. I need to revalidate the data for a **specific product**, for example, **/product/123**, when its content changes.

I am aware of the **revalidatePath** function, which allows revalidating data associated with a specific path. However, when I use revalidatePath with a dynamic segment such as revalidatePath('/product/[id]'), it revalidates **all segments under /product/[id]**.

Here is an example code snippet that demonstrates how to use the revalidatePath function:

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import { revalidatePath } from 'next/cache'

export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
  const path = request.nextUrl.searchParams.get('path') || '/'
  revalidatePath(path)
  return NextResponse.json({ revalidated: true, now: Date.now() })
}
```

The **Next.js version 13.4.6** documentation says that the revalidatePath function accepts a single parameter, path, which should be a string representing the **filesystem path associated with the data you want to revalidate**. This is **not the literal route segment**(e.g. /product/123), but instead, the path on the filesystem (e.g. /product/[id])​​.

**What I want to achieve** is to selectively revalidate only a specific product ID, like /product/123, without revalidating all the other segments under /product/[id].

Is there a way to achieve this **selective revalidation** in Next.js  13?

Any tested alternative strategies or best practices would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Has anyone encountered this problem?

Comment: Yes, I have same problem. Have huge amount of pages and don't want to revalidate them all if only one of them was edited. Did you find solution yet?

Comment: I have created similar question also on Nextjs-forum (https://nextjs-forum.com/post/1132806562814116020)

Comment: Github discussion about adding this as feature (https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/53154).

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation the problem is now solved.

The revalidatePath function now lets us revalidate the literal route segment from a dynamic path without revalidating all other dynamic segments aswell.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/revalidatePath